# Why is it only recognizing 5 of 6GB of RAM?

Tags: 13.10, ram

## Hardware

HP Envy M6 Sleekbook (m6-k010dx)
6GB RAM

I know it has 6GB of RAM, that's what it came with when I had Windows 8 on it, but the 13.10 install I've got (downloaded the latest two days ago) only sees 5. Did I configure something wrong?

## Settings

[image: Settings]

Please let me know what additional information may be necessary. I'm *very new* to Ubuntu.

Comment: I think your graphics uses shared memory. That means it takes away memory from the system RAM. So that 1 GiB is used by the graphics.

Comment: @falconer, that makes sense because it's almost certainly an on-board graphics card; this laptop came from Best Buy. So, is there a way in Ubuntu to just verify that by chance?

Comment: for me [this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-find-linux-vga-video-card-ram/) method correctly shows the shared memory taken away by my graphics. But with this APU thing I don't know.

Comment: Check your bios settings; there is usually a setting for how much ram to dedicate to the gpu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HD8610G is the video card with that laptop. It has no dedicated memory (some APUs have dedicated memory). It is supposed to be able to use up to 3GB of ram, but I can not find any details on how much it will use as a minimum.